# How Can I manipulate columns that contains lists to remove very similar elements using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has 2 columns: barcode and locus as shown below:

[image]

The locus column contains lists - some list only has one element while others can have many. As you can see from the circle value, there are some elements that share the chr number and last number but the middle number differs by a small amount compared to other elements in the same cell. I would like to remove the lower of the pairs and only keep one if the difference between the numbers in the middle is less than 5.

So far, I have split up the locus column into separate columns separated by the "-". So, I have 5 columns as shown below:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about this, but does anybody have an idea of how to filter out elements in these lists that are so closely related to other elements in the same cell?

EDIT:

Here is sample code (dictionary to DataFrame):

```
ex = {'CTCTTTCTCACCCCCCTCTT': '[chr6-249253-16, chr9-188167-0, chr4-1417473-0]',
     'CACCTATCACTACTACTTGT': '[chr11-438013-0, chr11-438014-0, chr11-438012-0]',
     'CCCGCTATCTATTGGCTTCT': '[chr2-335519-16]',
     'GATCCTCCCCGTTTCTTCAT': '[chr4-504274-0, chr4-504276-0]',
     'CTATCCCTTCTCATCCTGTT': '[chr16-518323-16, chr9-285852-16]'}

example = pd.DataFrame(ex.items())

example = example.rename(columns={0: "barcode", 1: "locus"})

print(example)
```

Here is a picture of the result and circles around the elements where the middle value is almost identical to the middle value of other elements in the same list in the same cell. I would like to remove the almost identical elements and only keep one of them.

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a sample dataset and an expected output?

Comment: I have just added sample data to my original question.